# Another database connection in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

So part of my layout for my theme needs to query a database other than the database made for wordpress.  I figured I would query the other database like normal.  I wrote a quick function to take care of it:

```
function my_function() {
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
  mysql_select_db("database", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("my query");
  mysql_close($con);
  $all = array();

  while ($all[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {}
  return $all;
}
```

I'm referencing the function in my header and realized it is breaking the categories in my sidebar.  What's going on?  I closed the connection I thought.  What am I doing wrong?  The error I get for the categories is this:

Warning: mysql_error(): 14 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1098

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is your custom database on the same mysql as the wordpress database?  Then you can still use the $wpdb object:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM brian_db.brian_table" );
```

Even if you can't do that, I'd still recommend using the Wordpress Database class for the sake of consistency, you can set up a new connection in that function:

```
$wpdb_b = new wpdb( "user", "password", "brian_db", "localhost" );
$wpdb_b->get_results( "SELECT * FROM brian_table" );
```

**update: corrected "global"**

Comment: Great you saved me!  Just a heads up there's a typo with $global should be global without the dollar sign.  Thanks again!